# Convert Embedded JSON to XML using XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt

When transforming an XML document with XSLT, is it possible to convert embedded JSON (i.e. JSON formatted content) in the process?

For example the following: -

```
<form>
    <data>[{"id":1,"name":"Hello"},{"id":2,"name":"World"}]</data>
</form>
```

Would be converted to: -

```
<form>
    <data>
        <id name="Hello">1</id>
        <id name="World">2</id>
    </data>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing JSON is supported in XSLT 3.0 so using the commercial versions of Saxon 9.7 you could use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="parse-json(.)?*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match=".[. instance of map(xs:string, item())]">
        <id name="{.?name}">
            <xsl:value-of select=".?id"/>
        </id>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using the open source version of Saxon 9.7 (i.e. Saxon 9.7 HE) the following takes up the suggestion made by wero to use `json-to-xml` and shows how to implement the requirement:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math fn"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)//fn:map"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fn:map">
        <id name="{fn:string[@key = 'name']}">
            <xsl:value-of select="fn:number[@key = 'id']"/>
        </id>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Saxon 9.7 HE is available on Maven and from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks but I fear a commercial offerring is beyond the scope of my project.. I was hoping for an XSLT 2.0 solution (the supported release within the Oracle 11gR2 database) OR an alternative method to support XSLT 3.0 within the Oracle database by importing a jar or whatever.

Comment: @AlbPuado, I have added an example that works with the open source HE edition of Saxon 9.7, it uses the function `json-to-xml` already suggested in the other answer. As for Oracle and XSLT 2.0, I am afraid I am not familiar with it and its features like extension functions, consider to tag your question with a specific tag if you are looking for a solution in that environment, perhaps than others familiar with it can tell you whether there are extension functions to parse and process JSON.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible in XSLT 3.0, given that it has a `json-to-xml` [function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#func-json-to-xml):

> Parses a string supplied in the form of a JSON text, returning the
>   results in the form of an XML document node.

You could try to get this to run with the current implementation in [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/changes/v9.3/xslt30.html).